# Social Enterprise using SharePoint?

Tags: social

Did you implemented Social Enterprise-like SharePoint projects? Do you have some guidelines/best practices regarding this topic? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We've implemented social enterprise around Comunities (building sites where people post articles, coment and rate), Social-Insight (e.g. how to benefit from Knowledge in-house by enabling communication and more synergies).
2. Achievements (take example of this site, MSDN forums) - via Activity feeds, Daniel McPherson give a great example (http://www.slideshare.net/danielmcpherson/intranets-2011-socialising-sharepoint)

For general description have a look here :

Have a look at these presentations to get more details on social from SharePoint (2010 at least) perspective, from Optimus via Slideshare http://www.slideshare.net/ram_prabhala/intranet-trends-best-practices-2011 in intranet.

As well as this about ROI in Social media http://sharepointsocial.de/2012/03/23/en-the-social-media-roi-conversation/

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 4):

There are also some great 3rd party tools if you have the budget for them. My company implemented Newsgator www.newsgator.com which sits on top of SharePoint and it has increased our cross-office collaboration 3-fold. SharePoint 2010 gives you a base platform but is still missing a lot from the social perspective.

Comment: I do custom development with NewsGator's Social Sites product using their web services and such. It really expands the OOTB social functionality of MySites. Enough so that Microsoft gave them Partner of the Year 2011. It's like Facebook meets Twitter... on SharePoint.